# Attaching in memory db to Physical database in sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite, cppsqlite

I have physical sqlite database and also an in memory db created using CppSqlite3 wrapper for sqlite_3 as,

```
CppSQLite3::Database memDb.open(":memory:")
```

I have also performed creating table to the above created db,and inserted some data to the table created.But when i am trying to Attach above inmemory db to a physical db connection say,

```
CppSQLite3::Database physicalDb.open("Path to db")
```

The attach query is as

"ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' as memDb"

The above query is executed in the space where the physicalDb connection has opened,but on execution of the query ,CppSqlite3 throws the following exception,

> > SQLITE_IOERR[10]: disk I/O error

Please suggest me the best way to resolve my promblem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably unrelated. Are you able to do anything else in the physical DB?

Comment: @CL. Ya ,i can select the data from physical db